# Dataflow programming vs Actor model

Tags: actor, dataflow

How can the difference between 'Dataflow Programming' and 'Actor model' be described? As far as I understand, they are not unrelated but yet are not the same.
Is DF a wider concept, which gist is the distinction from Control Flow model, while the Actor model is more elaborated and theoretically grounded inheritor of DF?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- Dataflow is deterministic which allows parallelism.
- Actors are non-deterministic which allows concurrency.

Comment: I did not think about this in such a way. Could you please elaborate a bit? 'Is deterministic' - does this mean that DF graph is hard-coded, thus we get the same result for same input; while Actor model allows dynamic graph reconfiguration, hence it is non-deterministic (at least may be so), right? But I cannot see a link between Parallelism vs concurrency and Deterministic vs Non-deterministic..

Comment: Seems like here is an explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8582580/why-is-concurrent-haskell-non-deterministic-while-parallel-haskell-primitives-p appropriate for me. BTW could you please recommend a CS literature where the distinction you've provided would be described?

Comment: The best book on declarative/dataflow concurrency is [Concepts, Techniques, and Models of Computer Programming](http://www.amazon.com/Concepts-Techniques-Models-Computer-Programming/dp/0262220695) by Peter Van Roy and Seif Haridi. It does a great job explaining the basics and how how it relates to both logic, FP and imperative style, covering actors, shared state concurrency and more on the way. Highly recommended.

Comment: Deterministic dataflow also allows for concurrency http://sites.uclouvain.be/blog-ingi/2011/12/making-concurrency-easy-with-deterministic-dataflow/. Also dataflow is not necessarily deterministic.

Comment: And what about deterministic algorithm if I put a random number generator somewhere into the middle of the data flow? ;-)

Answer (score 4):

DF is wider. A DF node may have several input ports, and is fired when all inputs are set. An Actor is a DF node with single input port. Colored Petri Net is even wider, allowing several transitions to be fed from single place, but it is hard to implement.

A DF implementation in Java can be found at [Dataflow4Java](https://github.com/rfqu/df4j).